# How do I renew ALL certificates with certbot?

Tags: letsencrypt, certbot

I don't want to only renew the certificates which are going to expire soon. (Whatever soon means). I want to renew all of them to make sure they will be on the same timing in the future.

I cannot find a way to do this with certbot. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `certbot -h renew` suggests:

```
renew:

  --force-renewal, --renew-by-default
                        If a certificate already exists for the requested
                        domains, renew it now, regardless of whether it is
                        near expiry.
```

Comment: you can have it run as a cronjob if you do `0 0 * * * certbot renew` as root.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the route from letsencrypt to my host was flaky that day and I needed an additional trick. Only some certificates succeeded on the first try and I didn't want to re-request them immediately.

If you want to renew only a specific certificate but really renew that you can use:

`certbot renew --cert-name example.com --force-renewal`

That saves you retyping all the domains in case you had multiple domains in that cert.